# How to register custom file extension to JavaScript editor in Visual Studio 2010/2012?

Tags: javascript, editor, file-extension

(Also refer the [original post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/scripting/thread/31700c7a-e640-473c-b5d8-2b77ea6d5dd6) on MSDN)

I have a very simple requirement which is to edit my own file extension (e.g. xsjs, xsapp...) with JavaScript editor in Visual Studio 2010/2012. Of course, these file extensions are fully ECMA standard compatible.

When I came to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension and added my own extension, there is no JavaScript editor at all:(  Then I chose the most likely option "Script Editor" (see figure below) and applied changes. But it didn't work for any of the registered extensions.

Am I missing something here? Any one tells me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible to do it in any version of Visual Studio. I just got confirmation from  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/748574/cannot-register-custom-file-extension-to-javascript-editor-in-visual-studio-2010-2012   I'm considering to use other editors (e.g. Eclipse) to accomplish the task.

Comment: Is there any hack or way to modify registry or something to achieve this? I urgently need such a thing. Even Community 2015 would do.

Answer (score 0):

1. Script editor is what you need. Afaik, there is no "javascript
   editor".
2. It's working for me. can you please explain what do you mean by "didn't work"

Comment: I get no javascript intellisense when I use "Script Editor" for my custom file extension.

Comment: It's not currently possible to do it in any version of Visual Studio. I just got confirmation from  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/748574/cannot-register-custom-file-extension-to-javascript-editor-in-visual-studio-2010-2012   I'm considering to use other editors (e.g. Eclipse) to accomplish the task.